# I get, "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name" in FF, and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" in IE, when importing D3 into Angular5

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular5

**UPDATE: My lead was able to solve this probllem. Please see answer below, and I hope that this helps at least some people**

The following code throws the exception, but note that when I don't import/use d3-selection, then the whole app runs without errors. As soon as I import select from 'd3-selection', I get the error that I mentioned in the title.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';

@Component({
    selector: 'pie',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class PieChartComponent {
    @ViewChild('containerPieChart')
    private element: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
        select(this.element.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

[image: chrome exception]

I checked the possible dupes in here, and none applied to me, so here I am.

The code that is bundled/imported from TypeScript is:

```
function(name) {
  return select(creator(name).call(document.documentElement));
}
```

I know this is invalid in JS, because functions must have names, or be IIFEs in order to omit the name. Or object declarations. So, why is d3 transpiling into invalid JS?

**EDIT:** I am using rollup.config.dev.js with the following code:

```
import bundles from './bundles.json';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
import sourcemaps from 'rollup-plugin-sourcemaps';

const
    DEV_DIRECTORY = `dev`
    , MODULE_NAME_PATH = 'AST.app'
;

function createDevBundle(bundle) {
    let bundleDirectory = `${DEV_DIRECTORY}/${bundle.name}`;

    return {
        input: bundle.input,
        name: `${MODULE_NAME_PATH}.${bundle.name}`,
        output: {
            file: `${bundleDirectory}/${bundle.name}.js`,
            format: 'umd'
        },
        exports: 'default',
        plugins: [
            resolve({
                jsnext: true,
                module: true
            }),
            commonjs(),
            sourcemaps(),
            scss({
                output: `${bundleDirectory}/${bundle.name}.css`,
                includePaths: ['../global/scss/base']
            })
        ],
        onwarn: function(warning) {
            // Recommended warning suppression by angular team.
            if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') {
                return;
            }

            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.error(warning.message);
        },
        treeshake: false,
        sourcemap: true
    };
}

export default bundles.map(createDevBundle);
```

Comment: Moving to D3V3 without type definitions as a workaround until I figure this bad boy out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to, but my lead was able to fix this problem. The following packages were updated in the **package.json**:

```
"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "8.3.0",
"rollup-plugin-execute": "1.0.0",
"rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "3.0.3",
"rollup-plugin-sourcemaps": "0.4.2",
"rollup-plugin-uglify": "3.0.0"
```

An update was made to **rollup.config.js** and **rollup.config.dev.js**. The sections of **name**, **exports**, and **sourcemap** were moved over to the **output** section. See below:

```
function createDevBundle(bundle) {
    let bundleDirectory = `${DEV_DIRECTORY}/${bundle.name}`;

    return {
        input: bundle.input,
        output: {
            file: `${bundleDirectory}/${bundle.name}.js`,
            name: `${MODULE_NAME_PATH}.${bundle.name}`,
            exports: 'default',
            sourcemap: true,
            format: 'umd'
        }
... [omitted for brevity]
```